# What does "pocketbook" mean here?

Tags: meaning, nouns

Does **pocketbook** in the following paragraph mean *3. Also, pocket book . a book, usually paperback, that is small enough to carry in one's coat pocket*. (Dictionary.com:http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pocketbook)?

These two paragraphs are taken from [NY Times](http://topics.nytimes.com/top/news/international/countriesandterritories/germany/index.html).

> As Germany embarks on this journey of self-discovery, the question is whether it will leave behind a European project which was built in no small measure on the nation’s postwar guilt and on its **pocketbook**.
>
> On the one hand, no nation has benefited more from the euro than Germany, whose trade surpluses come largely from imports by its European neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

["Pocketbook"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pocketbook) in this case is used to mean a budget. Although "pocketbook" is usually used to refer to a wallet(especially a woman's purse), in this case, it's being used figuratively:

> 2.(figuratively) One's personal budget or economic capacity - the amount one can afford.

Even in the link you provided, you can see, that, in view of the context, the definition most appropriate to the situation would be [number 2.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pocketbook)

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to your other question, *personification* is at work here. That is:

```
The attribution of a personal nature or human characteristics to something    
nonhuman, or the representation of an abstract quality in human form.
```

Just like a crisis can not actually drag along someone (dragging along someone requires a mind capable of higher thought, which only people have), a nation cannot actually have a pocketbook (a wallet).

If we look at what a wallet usually is -- just a place to keep our money -- we can reason that a pocketbook in this case simply represents the money that the nation has. The phrase one usually uses for this is budget.

Comment: The metaphor is not personification, it is metonymy, meaning by association of pocketbook with the much larger community budget.